# How to order database insert?

Tags: sql, database

I want to insert a row in the db table, such that the newly inserted row is the first row that shows up on SELECT * FROM tablename ?

Typically DB insert will insert a row1 below an existing row0 and select statement would first return r0 and then r1. In other words is behaves like a queue.

Now I want to insert r2, such that r2 shows up before r0 ?

Comment: does inserting really matter? thought should handled on how you display them

Comment: If you *do NOT* specify an explicit `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT`, then the ordering of the rows returned is **undefined** and cannot be guaranteed. There's absolutely no point in trying to *order the `INSERT`* - the only way to achieve ordering is to **explicitly define an `ORDER BY`** clause on your `SELECT` ....

Comment: "Typically DB insert will insert a row1 below an existing row0 and select statement would first return r0 and then r1. In other words is behaves like a queue.". Nope that's completely incorrect.

Comment: http://www.sql-workbench.net/not-sorted/

Answer (score 3):

The order of a select sentence without ORDER BY clause is not deterministic and can differ each time you query the data. The correct way to achieve what you ask for is to use ORDER BY in the SELECT sentence and have a column to hold the rank of the result in the table and order by that column. For better performance, that column could be used as a clustered index.